# 4.4.2 KitKat app name truncation

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, home-screen-shortcuts

Since a month or two the app titles on my homescreen keep getting truncated even though there is more than enough space.
An example would be "Settings" which gets truncated to "S..."
Moving an app around the screen seems to refresh it, and after that it does show the full app name.
I've tried modifying font size, but that doesn't fix it. 
The phone itself is up-to-date, and not rooted.
The same thing occurs in the menus and app drawer, but that's much less of an inconvenience.

Is there any way to turn off truncation of the app names (or if that's not possible, an app that takes over the home screen and doesn't truncate the names)?

My data:
Android 4.4.2
Acer E39 E700 Liquid

Comment: Time to switch launchers maybe?

Comment: A lot simpeler than I realised; looks like it's an Acer Home launcher issue (not updateable as a launcher). Just installed Nova Launcher, which seems to work nicely, and indeed that doesn't have any issues so far. Thanks!

Comment: So maybe time to post an answer with the solution and accept it? Any of you two ([self-answering](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is completely fine here) could do that :)

Comment: Ha! Great. You'd be surprised how much people can't get used to a different launcher. Nova FTW!

Comment: Tip: in Nova Settings -> Desktop -> Icon and layout -> uncheck Single line to stop truncation of labels on home screen or tick it to start truncation.